# limit_req, exclude php file and route

Tags: php, nginx

I have a script that show images and i'm trying to exclude the following php route from limit_req

```
rewrite ^/([^\@]*)\@(\d+x\d+)$ /index.php?route=image&action=show&path=$1&size=$2 break;
```

I have

```
location ~ .php$ {
    limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=3 nodelay;
    limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 3;

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

for images and other file formats I used

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|css|less|xml|html?|swf|js|ttf)$ {
    expires 10y;
}
```

so how can I exclude the route (index.php?route=image) from limit_req in nginx config?

LE:

I tried something like but I receive an error " nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "off"

```
location ~ .php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

    limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=3 nodelay;
    limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 3;

    location ~ "/foo/(.+)$" {
        limit_req off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http {
   .....
      map $arg_route $limit {
      default $binary_remote_addr;
      "image" "";
    }
      limit_req_zone $limit zone=one:10m rate=3r/s;
   .....
}

server {
    .....
    limit_req zone=one burst=5;
    .....
}
```

I hope there is no need to explain something here and everything is clear. Using **map** is better, because ifisevil.
You also can replace $arg_route with $request_uri.

Comment: I have the following error: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:15

Comment: No errors but it doesn't works. I also tried with $request_uri

Comment: What does it mean 'doesn't work'? What was nginx behavior? Have you noted that zone name in my answer is 'one'?

Comment: and the behavior of the nginx is that not all images are loaded http://prntscr.com/hd9grj

Comment: no, no.. $request_uri could not be "image". $request_uri is a full original request uri with args such as "/index.php?arg1=2&arg2=3".

Comment: check this https://serverfault.com/questions/184058/how-can-i-use-wildcards-in-an-nginx-map-directive

Comment: i can not figure it out